# matchShapes between images of contours

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, pattern-matching

[In this example tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html#find-contours) an image is made out of contours. A contour is a vector of Points. [matchShapes](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#double%20matchShapes(InputArray%20contour1,%20InputArray%20contour2,%20int%20method,%20double%20parameter)) performs a comparison between such contours. But a Mat image is made out of multiple contours. It is a `vector<vector<Point>>`, for instance, in the example from the tutorials, `drawing` is made from multiple overlapped contours.

My question is if I have 2 Mat objects, how to compare them using matchShapes? I want to compare the images themselves, not each contour. That means I want to compare `vector<vector<Point>>` and not just `vector<Point>`

I can't compare each element of the two vectors, though. It needs to be a comparison between the overlapping of them.

Original

[image]

Canny contours with a threshold of 85

[image]
This image is made out of `contours.size()` contours, overlapped with eachother. How can I compare this with other similar examples? (obviously comparing it with itself should  be a perfect match, but I don't know how to do that)

I need to find a way to compare it as a whole rather than take each `contours` and compare it.
For instance, if I want to do it with this one:

[image]

Comment: The contours of one image are position related. E.g. the head of the fish is left of the tail with a measurable distance. You can find the best fitting contours between images, then check those inter-contour constraints over both images.

Comment: In that case, how can I compare two fishes? Since one fish image will be composed of different contours.

Comment: i think you have to post sample images (raw and contours) that you want to match to make clear what exactly you want to achieve and what kind of problems occur.

Comment: you could try to group those contours (fingers) to objects (hand) and use chamfer matching between objects of different images. But in general i think this task is too complex for simple shape matching techniques! in fact, it's question of definition whether both images show the same shape at all - one has part of arm included and the thumbs are not aligned the same way!

Comment: I was thinking of using convex hull and compare the two convex hulls between them. The thing is that matchShapes will return a value closer to 0, the more similar they are. That's what interests me. To cut the hand without arm..maybe convexity defects on the wrist?

Comment: yea, try chamfer matching as a beginning (or chamfer matching for your convex hulls). but objects must be in same scale and orientation.

Comment: you could even try `cv::matchTemplate`

Comment: matchTemplate doesn't work really like I want it. It detects 2 hands very similar. For instance, it will treat the palm part of a closed fist(the part close to the wrist) and an open palm like the same. If I want it to detect hands in general I'd use Haar cascade classifier, but what I want is to recognize between different hand shapes.

Comment: Should still be open research topic... have a look at the video and the proposed link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_N41CP0f0Mg

Comment: That's kind of similar to what I want to achieve. They don't really explain how they did it, though.

Comment: here they explain it (if you have access): http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0262885611000151

Comment: I don't, unfortunately.

Comment: Any way I can do it myself, even if not as good?

Comment: the paper doesnt look like the implementation would be trivial. They some special shape descriptor and a matching method for those descriptors. maybe you can have a look at other shape descriptors like http://www.math.uci.edu/icamp/summer/research_11/park/shape_descriptors_survey.pdf